# EF Core in-memory database updates value without calling DbContext SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, xunit, in-memory-database

I have a problem I have not experienced before. In a test using EF Core in-memory database child properties are modified even though no `SaveChanges` is called. I know of the limitations of the built in  in-memory database but I did not expect values to be saved without a `SaveChanges` anyway.

- It is not a relational database.
- It doesn't support transactions.
- It cannot run raw SQL queries.
- It is not optimized for performance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database

Example classes:

```
public class Text
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public List<QuestionText> QuestionTexts { get; set; } = new List<QuestionText>();
}

public class Question
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public List<QuestionText> QuestionTexts { get; set; } = new List<QuestionText>();
}


public class QuestionText
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }

    public int TextId { get; set; }

    public Text Text { get; set; }
}
```

xUnit Test:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
         .Options;

    var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);

    var description1 = "Description 1";
    var description2 = "Description 2";
    var text1 = new Text()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Description = description1
    };

    var questionText1 = new QuestionText()
    {
        Text = text1
    };

    var text2 = new Text()
    {
        Id = 2,
        Description = description2,
    };

    var questionText2 = new QuestionText()
    {
        Text = text2
    };

    var question = new Question();
    question.QuestionTexts.Add(questionText1);
    question.QuestionTexts.Add(questionText2);

    dbContext.Questions.Add(question);

    //Works
    Assert.Null(dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault()); 

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    //Works
    Assert.NotNull(dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault());

    //Works
    Assert.Equal(2 ,dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionTexts.Count);

    var question2 = dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault();

    question2.QuestionTexts = question.QuestionTexts.Where(x => x.Text.Id == 1).ToList();

    //Only one QuestionTexts left even though no save has been performed
    Assert.Equal(2, dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionTexts.Count);

    dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);
    //Question is till there but QuestionTexts are 0
    Assert.Equal(2, dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionTexts.Count);
}
```

Is this an expected outcome?

Comment: Would be a nice to know, but the documentation (not limited to link provided) is quite clear that in-memory db shouldn't be used as in your example. Suffice to say, not much reason is given around these pitfalls.

Comment: @AbdulG True but I still think it is very weird that the object is updated in the database when a local change is performed without a save.

Answer (score 1):

For this:

```
//Only one QuestionTexts left even though no save has been performed
Assert.Equal(2, dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionTexts.Count);
```

This would be expected behaviour. EF DbContexts deals with references. When you retrieve `dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault()` especially with only one question in the DbContext you receive a reference to a Question. Asking later for `dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault()` will return the same reference (including any changes you have made) so long as you haven't turned off instance tracking or used `AsNoTracking()`.

That said, I would strongly recommend avoiding the "OrDefault" methods unless the presence is optional, and avoid using "First" type methods without specifying an OrderBy. If you expect one, and only one row, use `Single()`. If you want the first row by ID then `.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First()` for example.

Next, statements like this:

```
question2.QuestionTexts = question.QuestionTexts.Where(x => x.Text.Id == 1).ToList();
```

... should never be used in EF entities. Never replace collection references. You should also declare your collection references as `virtual`, and declared as `ICollection<TEntity>` to fully facilitate EF's proxy implementations. This will help ensure that change tracking works as expected when interacting with the collection.

```
public virtual ICollection<QuestionText> QuestionTexts { get; set; } = new List<QuestionText>();
```

Then when you want to test removing an item:

```
question2.QuestionTexts.Remove(question.QuestionTexts.Single(x => x.Text.Id == 1));
```

I'd normally split this to avoid data concurrency issues, such as a client requesting to remove an item that has already been removed since the client last referenced it:

```
var questionTextToRemove = question.QuestionTexts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Text.Id == 1);
if(questionTextToRemove != null)
    question2.QuestionTexts.Remove(questionTextToRemove);
```

This one:

```
dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);
//Question is till there but QuestionTexts are 0
Assert.Equal(2, dbContext.Questions.FirstOrDefault().QuestionTexts.Count);
```

... is curious. It may be a side effect for the issue above, replacing the non-virtual List, or a peculiarity of the in-memory DbContext.